# Use JS to redirect if a cookie is setted, until it expire

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm working on this code, so that when "YES" is clicked, "music_player" is setted to "true", this way the next time the user visit that page if the cookie is setted to "true" he's being redirected to another page, until the cookie expire, the next day (like a 1 day ban).The point is that I did something wrong and really can't find what's missing/wrong.

```
<script>

    function music_player(){
    days=1; // number of days to keep the cookie
    myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    document.cookie = 'music_player=true; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
    }

    function ReDirect (URL) {         
    GetCookie('music_player');
    if (GetCookie('music_player') == 'true') {
    window.location=('/Banned_Dead');
    }
    else {}
    }

</script>
<a href="#" onclick="music_player()">YES</a>
```

Comment: Where is the function `GetCookie` defined? Normally, you access cookies like you set them (`document.cookie`).

Comment: is that what I'm doing wrong? I'm not confident with js, could you please give a fix ?

Comment: Then probalby yes. Take a look at section "A Function to Get a Cookie" on http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp. This could be your implementation for the `getCookie` method. Take care of case sensitivity.